# Angular Signal compute doesn't trigger re-render

Tags: angular

I have to sort a signal's array in my component, to do so I wrap it in a compute which sorts it.

The relevant code:

Service:

```
private readonly _lobbies = signal<Lobby[]>([]);
public readonly lobbies = this._lobbies.asReadonly();
```

Component:

```
public lobbies = computed(() =>
  this._lobbyService.lobbies().sort((a, b) => (a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1))
);
```

Template:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let lobby of lobbies()">
 ...
</tr>
```

If I remove the computed and work against the signal directly, it re-renders correctly when updating the signal array, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Well sort is an in place sort and returns the reference to the same array. Given it's marked as readonly in the service I'm not sure it *should* succeed. Best practice would be to return a new array in the computed

Comment: This seems to work if I first spread the signal's array like this 

`public lobbies = computed(() =>
    [...this._lobbyService.lobbies()].sort((a, b) => (a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1))
  );`

Comment: you create a new reference when you spread.

Comment: @AndrewAllen you can mark your comment as answer, it works when spreading the signal's array

Comment: will do. Is there a use case for `.asReadonly()` over putting the computed logic (which makes the signal readonly) directly in the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE ANGULAR 17**

The mutated function is no longer available and from Angular 17 it is necessary to use Update

```
AddLobby() {
   this._lobbies.update(values => {
      values.push({ id: this.i++ });
      return values;
   })
}
```

---

I try to recreate the problem but it still working.
The only difference (i think), i use mutate for adding lobby.

TestService.ts

```
import { Injectable, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { lobby } from './lobby';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TestService {
    private readonly _lobbies = signal<lobby[]>([
        {
          id: 2
        },
        {
          id: 1
        }
      ]);
      public readonly lobbies = this._lobbies.asReadonly();

      i = 0;
      AddLobby() {
        this._lobbies.mutate(values => {
            values.push({ id: this.i++ })
          })
      }
}
```

SignInComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.css']
})
export class SignInComponent {
  
  public lobbies = computed(() =>
    this.testService.lobbies().sort((a, b) => (a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1))
  );
  

  constructor(
      public testService: TestService
  ) { 
  }

  add() {
    this.testService.AddLobby();
  }
}
```

SignIn template

```html
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let lobby of lobbies()">
        {{ lobby.id }}
    </tr>
</table>

<button (click)="add()">test</button>
```

Comment: Mutate has been removed in favour of update only (immutable data patterns)

Comment: @AndrewAllen where i find that info? In the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/signals) of angular thay say: "When working with signals that contain objects, it's sometimes useful to mutate that object directly. For example, if the object is an array, you may want to push a new value without replacing the array entirely. To make an internal change like this, use the .mutate method"

Comment: See [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/c7ff9dff2c14aba70e92b9e216a2d4d97d6ef71e) against [PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/51821)

Comment: @AndrewAllen thx... :) when i have time i change the response... thx

Comment: Awesome response and awesome comment. Leave the mutate example as deprecated please and leave the new way to do things too. Thanks.